# How to generate PEM from Curve25519 public key

Tags: ios, swift, bouncycastle, ecdh, apple-cryptokit

I want to use ECC (curve25519) with Diffie-Hellman Key exchange. Backend is using ECC with X9.62 and PKCS#8 encoding. I want to achieve same on iOS so that I can fetch data from backed, decrypt it and show it to user.

I tried this code but didn't work

```
func getPEM() -> String {
    let keyPair = Curve25519.Signing.PrivateKey()
    let pubKey = keyPair.publicKey
    let pem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\(pubKey.rawRepresentation.base64EncodedString())-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
    
    return pem
}
```

After searching on Google I found that In order to get PEM we need DER and ASN1 from my public key but they are not supported by `CryptoKit`.

Android is able to get right PEM using `bouncycastle`. Just for reference I am posting snippet from android code base.

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ECParameters
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.ec.CustomNamedCurves
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.EC5Util
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
import java.security.*
import java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec

object CryptoKeyGenerator {

    init {
        Security.removeProvider(BOUNCY_CASTLE_IDENTIFIER)
        Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())
    }

    fun getClientKeyMaterial(): String {
        val keyPair = generateEphemeralKeyPair()
        val pemEncodedPublicKey = getPEMEncodedStream(keyPair.public, false)
        return pemEncodedPublicKey
    }

    private fun getPEMEncodedStream(key: Key, privateKey: Boolean): String {
        val pkcS8EncodedKeySpec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key.encoded)
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        val keyType = if(privateKey) PRIVATE_KEY else PUBLIC_KEY
        stringBuilder.append(KEY_HEADER_START + keyType + KEY_HEADER_END)
        stringBuilder.append(CryptoUtils.getBase64Encoded(pkcS8EncodedKeySpec.encoded))
        stringBuilder.append(KEY_FOOTER_START + keyType + KEY_HEADER_END)
        return stringBuilder.toString()
    }

    /**
    * This method generates an ECC KeyPair with Curve25519 specs
    */
    private fun generateEphemeralKeyPair(): KeyPair {
        val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(EC_ALGO_IDENTIFIER, BOUNCY_CASTLE_IDENTIFIER)
        val eccParameters: X9ECParameters = CustomNamedCurves.getByName(ECC_CURVE_SPEC)
        val eccSpec: ECParameterSpec = EC5Util.convertToSpec(eccParameters)
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(eccSpec)
        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
    }
}
```

Android generated PEM key look like this
`MIIBMTCB6gYHKoZIzj0CATCB3gIBATArBgcqhkjOPQEBAiB/////////////////////////////////////////7TBEBCAqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqYSRShRAQge0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0JgtenHcQyGQEQQQqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq0kWiCuGaG4oIa04B7dLHdI0UySPU1+bXxhsinpxaJ+ztPZAiAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFN753qL3nNZYEmMaXPXT7QIBCANCAAQwsdIRTVn2+6rlgqAhVvx7ERj/Oku0wHmZZU1OST617h95ygSP5zJOa9lNiKqZMArjtJh7yQ4rg7kUq08Nv8+Q`

This repo has samples for java, c and Nodejs
https://github.com/Sahamati/rahasya

Comment: PEM is not using raw representation, it is using DER representation, so you need to use ASN1 encoding, see answer here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679787

Comment: solution given in link developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679787 does not work. We have solved this problem. We had to use https://github.com/leif-ibsen/SwiftECC. I will add detailed answer.

Comment: @kmithi1 can you help with that detailed answer? I am facing the same issue, and apple forums are not helping a lot (saw your post on that one too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CryptoKit you won't be able to do this. You will need to use SwiftECC library(https://github.com/leif-ibsen/SwiftECC).

Step 1 - Create a `Domain` specifically for Curve25519

```
struct Curve25519Domain {
    static let domainName = "x25591"
    static func getInstance() -> Domain? {
        guard let p = BInt("7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffed", radix: 16),
              let a = BInt("2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa984914a144", radix: 16),
              let b = BInt("7b425ed097b425ed097b425ed097b425ed097b425ed097b4260b5e9c7710c864", radix: 16),
              let gx = BInt("2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad245a", radix: 16),
              let gy = BInt("20ae19a1b8a086b4e01edd2c7748d14c923d4d7e6d7c61b229e9c5a27eced3d9", radix: 16),
              let order = BInt("1000000000000000000000000000000014def9dea2f79cd65812631a5cf5d3ed", radix: 16) else {
            return nil
        }
        // returns nil if fails to create a domain
        return try? Domain.instance(name: domainName,
                                    p: p,
                                    a: a,
                                    b: b,
                                    gx: gx,
                                    gy: gy,
                                    order: order,
                                    cofactor: 8)
    }
}
```

Step 2 - Generate Public Key

```
if let domain = Curve25519Domain.getInstance() {
    let keyPair = domain.makeKeyPair()
    let privateKey = keyPair.1
    let publicKey = keyPair.0
}
```

Step 3 - Encapsulate the public key in PEM format -

```
func getPEMofPublicKey(publicKey: ECPublicKey) -> String? {
    let base64Encoded = Data(publicKey.der).base64EncodedString()
    let pemString = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\(base64Encoded)-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
    return pemString
}
```

I have also posted a detailed solution in a medium article, which also includes decryption -
https://medium.com/@k.mohsin11/decrypting-financial-data-in-account-aggregator-ios-app-30d672ad4426

Let me know if you are still stuck.